# Get someones ip address from name and email

Tags: ip, ip-address, privacy

I want to know if it's possible to get someones' IP address if I have their name, email and ID.

Comment: How is this programming-related ?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. That person could access your application from *anywhere*, and if all you have are his name, email and user ID, that's not going to tell you anything about what machine he's coming from.

Comment: My application?? I just wanted to find somebody, and I have his full name, social security and email. I just wanted his ip address, which would at least tell me in what country he is living.

Comment: @Carlos: You cannot determine someone's IP using that information alone.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by his id?  An email address and a name are not sufficient to retrieve an IP.